# Function didn't change the value - JAVA 6 SE

Tags: java

I can't understand why the overloaded function 'increase' does not change Integer but does change Point.
The propuse of 'Integer' class is to wrap int so it will be a reference Type.

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ///1
        Integer i = new Integer(0);
        increase(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        ///2
        Point p = new Point(0,0);
        increase(p);
        System.out.println(p);

    }

    public static void increase(Integer i){
        i = 1;
    }

    public static void increase(Point p){
        p.setLocation(1, 1);
    }
}
```

**the output is :**

```
0
java.awt.Point[x=1,y=1]
```

Also, is their a simple way to pass a variable to a function by reference in Java?

Comment: And *this* is what happens when you mix things up and say that "Java uses pass-by-reference".

Answer (score 6):

Integer class is an immutable class, that means its content can't be changed after it's created.

Also, Java is pass-by-value so the variable `i` is passed by value, and the fact that it changes inside the function has no effect on the caller.

Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object for more information on immutable objects.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that Java uses pass by value, not pass by reference.

In the `Point` case, the method is changing a field of the point object whose reference was passed into the method.

In the `Integer` case, the method is simply assigning a new value to the local variable `i`.  This does not update the variable `i` in the calling method, because Java uses pass by reference.

The other issue is that `Integer` has no `setValue` methods because it is immutable.  If you want to do the equivalent of what the `Point` version of the method is doing, you will have to define an `IntegerHolder` class that has both a getter and a setter, together with methods such as `increase`, that your application needs.  (Alternatively, find such a class in a 3rd party library.)

Comment: There is the `java.util.concurrent.AtomicInteger` class, which additionally to being mutable also is usable for multi-thread use.

Comment: Yes ... but you may not want the overheads inherent in the atomic operations.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` objects are immutable, i.e. you can't change them. If you could, the syntax would be like

```
i.setValue(1);
```

If you want to pass a non-object by reference, you can either wrap it in an array of length 1 or (better) create a trivial wrapper. However, there is little reason to do so - don't port your code from C 1:1. Usually, you should have a semantically loaded object, like an `Account` on which you can call the `increase` and `decrease` (or maybe just `setBalance`) methods.

Comment: Integer is immutable but how did u set the value to 1!!

Comment: @Suresh S there is not actually a setValue method on Integers. That's why they are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

In this function:

```
public static void increase(Integer i){
    i = 1;
}
```

autoboxing makes this equivalent to:

```
public static void increase(Integer i){
    i = new Integer(1);
}
```

i.e. it changes the *reference* that `i` contains, not the *value* that it contains.  The `Integer` object is itself immutable, there's actually no way to change the value of one after it has been created.

Since that reference is a local variable, any changes to it will not affect the variable that was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `i = 1`, you are changing the `i` parameter to point to a new boxed `Integer` instance.
The original `Integer` instance that you passed to the function is not—and cannot be—changed—`Integer`s are immutable

Answer (score 0):

Answer here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-06/01-qa-0602-immutable.html
This reference could be useful: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the two methods to be equivalent, the second one would look like this:

```
public static void increase(Point p){
    p = new Point(1, 1);
}
```

And then you would see that it outputs the original point here, too.

**There is no  *pass a variable to a function by reference* in Java.**

You can simulate it by passing an object which contains the variable (like you did in your `increase(Point)` method) - you'll have to be sure to assign to the variable, though, not to the object containing the variable.

As said before, there are several "mutable wrappers" around (for example `org.omg.CORBA.IntHolder` and `java.util.concurrent.AtomicInteger` in the standard API), but it is not difficult to create your own, and in most cases it would be better to use a sensible "Business object" like an "Account" instead.